# Font not loadable

Tags: fonts, errors, miktex

I don't have much experience with font usage, so I'm a bit perplexed about this error that I'm getting.

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\eiad{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{eiad}\selectfont}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

{\eiad nil na la, ta na la }
\end{document}
```

gives me the following error:

```
Font OT1/eiad/m/n/10=eiadr10 at 10.0pt is not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

I installed the eiad package with MiKTeX's package editor, and it has an `eiadr10.mf` file in it, but no `.tfm` files. Am I missing a file, or have I done something else wrong?

Comment: Did you refresh the database?

Comment: Have you seen "Most fount files consult the files from the Sauter distribution for parameters, so you have to download and install them before you can generate the founts.  Sauter is available from CTAN." in the readme file?

Comment: @Sigur When a package is installed witht the package manager the fontname data base routine is called automatically.